# Mockito verify method was called with set, that contains specific value

Tags: mockito, verify

I want to be sure that mocked is called with specific set of strings as parameter.
For example, I have the following code:

```
public class SomeLogic {
    @Autowired
    private SpecificService specificService;

    public void action() {
        Set<String> args = fillArgsMethod();
        specificService.handleArgs(args);
    }
}
```

And my current try to test it is the following

```
@Mock
private SpecificService specificService
@InjectMocks
private SomeLogic someLogic;

@Test
public void testAction() {
    someLogic.action();
    verify(specificService).handleArgs(anySet());
}
```

But I want to be sure, that handleArgs() will receive the exact set of strings, that I expect. How can I modify verifying to check that handleArgs is called with set "first","second"?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prepare your `Set` parameters before calling the test method

```
    @Test
    public void testAction() {
        Set<String> expectedParams = new HashSet(Arrays.asList("first", "second");
        //call tested method
        verify(specificService).handleArgs(expectedParams);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I need Hamcrest methods, but the solution appeared to be much more simplier

Comment: You're welcome. I use Hamcrest because it has better matchers and better reporting when a test fails.

Answer (score 11):

Isah gave a valid answer, but I want to turn your attention to a more general feature of Mockito which is [ArgumentCaptor](http://rapaul.com/2010/06/10/avoiding-brittle-tests-with-mockitos-argument-captor/)

In you case you would do something along the following lines:

```
Class<HashSet<String>> setClass = (Class<HashSet<String>>)(Class)HashSet.class;
ArgumentCaptor<Set<String>> setCaptor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(setClass .class);

verify(specificService).create(setCaptor.capture());
HashSet<String> capturedSet = setCaptor.getValue();

//do whatever test you want with capturedSet
```

Comment: In this case it is probably overkill, but you get the general idea of how this is a more general solution :)

Answer (score 9):

isah's solution is perfect for you if you want to confirm that the set contains exactly the two items you specify; Mockito compares using `.equals` by default, and [`Set.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is defined as refer to equal elements in any order.

For a more-flexible "contains" test that matches your question title, that allows for set members beyond your expected values, you can also use [the Hamcrest `contains` matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)):

```
someLogic.action();
verify(specificService).handleArgs(argThat(contains("first", "second")));
```

At least, that's how it *should* look. Unfortunately, `argThat` infers its return type from the Matcher, which infers its return type from the arguments, so Java assumes your first argument is not a `Set<String>` but a `Iterable<capture#1-of ? extends String>`. You'll need to cast explicitly and suppress warnings to get it to work:

```
// requires @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
verify(specificService).handleArgs(
    (Set<String>) argThat(contains("first", "second")));
```